# Flexbox: Two elements on top of each other in flex-direction: row

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve the following:

[image]

---

My first attempt was to use a helper div (green):

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89z21rq3/7/)

What I could do here, is using JavaScript to move the puple and orange elements out of the helper on mobile screens. **But there has to be a plain css way.**

---

My second attempt was to remove the helper and build the Mobile Layout:

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umq3L2wL/1/)

---

Is there a way to place two elements on top of each other in `flex-direction: row`? ([second attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/umq3L2wL/1/))

Comment: No, not really, that's why we have column layout. CSS can sort of do this *with* the helper using `display:contents` but its only supported by FF.

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use flexbox? It could be done with traditional positioning.

Comment: I think that responsive css and traditional positioning will work well for what you need to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Okay, didn't know `display: contents` before. Definitely something to watch.
@4castle: I don't actually have to use flexbox. I was using it a lot lately and intuitively tried to do this with it as well.
@Taylor: Thanks, I probably was a bit too focussed on that shiny flexbox stuff :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this with `Flexbox` but you need to use fixed `height` on flex container. Here is [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/89z21rq3/8/)

Basically you use `flex-wrap: wrap` with `flex-direction: column` and make first item take 100% height and set `width` in %. Then you change order with media queries and height.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main,
div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.desktop {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  flex: 1;
  width: 30%;
}
[orange] {
  background-color: #FFAD77;
  flex: 0 0 70%;
}
[yellow] {
  background-color: #FFE377;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 70%;
}
[purple] {
  background-color: #FF77C8;
}
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop div {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  div[orange] {
    order: -1;
    flex: 2;
  }
  div[yellow] {
    flex: 5;
  }
  div[purple] {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop">
  <div yellow>lorem</div>
  <div orange>lorem</div>
  <div purple>lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.. *"Is there a way to place two elements on top of each other in flex-direction: **row**"*

Comment: yes if the sum of their width greater than the widht of the parent and the parent has flex-wrap: wrap

Comment: I guess this is as far as you can get with rows https://jsfiddle.net/89z21rq3/10/

Comment: Sometimes I will probably have to take no as an answer. And as there are very good alternatives, I willingly do in this case :) Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

No, but the alternative isn't deadly. If you use absolute positioning, you will have much more control over the layout at different screen sizes.

```js
function toggleLayout() {
  document.querySelector('main').classList.toggle('mobile');
}
```

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

main div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}

main.mobile div {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.3%;
}

[orange] {
  background-color: #FFAD77;
  bottom: 40%;
  left: 66.6%;
}

[yellow] {
  background-color: #FFE377;
  right: 33.3%;
}

[purple] {
  background-color: #FF77C8;
  top: 60%;
  left: 66.6%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div orange></div>
  <div yellow></div>
  <div purple></div>
</main>
<button onclick="toggleLayout()">toggleLayout</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if you use a helper wrapper, then you will only be able to reorder the items inside it, but not mix them with their uncles.

And if you don't use a helper wrapper, you need a column layout. And the only widely supported way to break columns is hardcoding a height to the contaner, as Nenad Vracar suggested. But sometimes you can't do that.

I will suggest two better alternatives, but they have poor support (basically, Firefox):

- Use a helper wrapper for desktop and get rid of it with `display: contents` in mobile

  ```js
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('main').classList.toggle('mobile');
  });
  ```

  ```css
  main {
    display: flex;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  div {
    flex: 1;
  }
  [data-color=orange] {
    background-color: #FFAD77;
  }
  [data-color=yellow] {
    background-color: #FFE377;
  }
  [data-color=purple] {
    background-color: #FF77C8;
    order: 3;
  }
  main.mobile {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  main.mobile .wrapper {
    display: contents;
  }
  main.mobile [data-color=orange] {
    order: -1;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <main>
    <div data-color="yellow"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div data-color="orange"></div>
      <div data-color="purple"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <button>toggleLayout</button>
  ```
- Use forced line breaks

  ```js
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('main').classList.toggle('mobile');
  });
  ```

  ```css
  main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  div {
    flex: 1;
  }
  [data-color=orange] {
    background-color: #FFAD77;
    page-break-after: always;
    break-after: always;
  }
  [data-color=yellow] {
    background-color: #FFE377;
  }
  [data-color=purple] {
    background-color: #FF77C8;
    order: 3;
  }
  main.mobile {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  main.mobile [data-color=orange] {
    order: -1;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <main>
    <div data-color="yellow"></div>
    <div data-color="orange"></div>
    <div data-color="purple"></div>
  </main>
  <button>toggleLayout</button>
  ```

Comment: Well that's neat, but as you said something that is probably a possible solution for the future :) Thanks